# Schengen visa - Travelling to Italy

Tags: visas, schengen, italy

Please guide. Traveling to India from USA. Am on Green Card in USA. Wanted to take a tourist stop of couple of weeks in Italy on the way. Problem is seems I will need a visa for my Italy stop. The Italian embassy do not have a interview date until July this is way past my travel dates. Kindly advise if I can get a Schengen visa from any other country for my travel to Italy. As indicated am stopping only in Italy and no other country in Europe this itinerary. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no, if Italy is your primary destination then any other country will reject your application because they are not competent to consider it under the rules laid out in the [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412).

All is not lost, however, since you're hoping to stop over for "a couple of weeks."  If you can find a country that has appointments available, you can plan a trip to that country.  You can even travel to that country from Milan or Rome or whatever stopover point you were planning to use in Italy.  In fact, you can spend a few days in Italy or other Schengen countries as long as you will spend more time in the country that has available appointments than you will in any other Schengen country.

(Duration of visit is not the only criterion that can make a country your main destination, but in your case it seems like the only one that could realistically be reasonable.)